# jQuery taking value from object

Tags: javascript

I have an object, I want to take a value, for example "title1", what function should I use to solve the problem.
please help me.

```
[{ 
   total1 : "1200",
   total2 : "800",
   title1 : "Birth Rate",
   title2 : "Death Rate",
   year : "2011" 
}]
```

sorry for my mistake..that data is the result from console.log()
The data derived from

```
    $( ".residentgraph" ).each(function(i,el) { 
        var ids = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $('#'+ids).val();
        var dataVal = value.split("/");

        chartData.push({
            'title1' : dataVal[0],
            'title2' : dataVal[1],
            'total1' : dataVal[2],
            'total2' : dataVal[3],
            'year' : dataVal[4]
        });          
    });
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery or functions. It's a trivial matter of JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I have changed my question. sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are having this array in a variable called `xArr`,

```
console.log(xArr[0].title1);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B6W5J/)